# Which one is the VOO ETF I'm looking for?

Tags: united-states, etf, vanguard, interactive-brokers

I'm starting my investment education. From udemy - *Complete Investing Course 2021 (Stocks, ETFs Investing)* I found I should look for VOO ETF.

[image]

So I searched for it on IBRK but there are many:

[image]

So which one is the VOO ETF I'm looking for?

I have no idea what's PSE or ARCA. Does MEXI stand for Mexico?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Vanguard S&P 500 ETF](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/portfolio/voo) is listed on the [NYSE ARCA](https://www.nyse.com/markets/nyse-arca) stock exchange. "VOO" is the ticker symbol of the Vanguard S&P 500 ETF's listing on NYSE ARCA. This ETF is traded in many places, including on the Mexico Stock Exchange's Global Market (SIC).

"VOO ARCA" appears to be the one you are looking for, because it is the official listing and has the highest trading volume.

"VOO.IV" represents the intraday indicative value of "VOO". If I understand correctly, that is a number derived from the price of "VOO", not something you can actually trade.

Comment: What's so special about Mexico? Why don't I see other countries/regions also (i.e. UK, Germany, China)?

Comment: @ebepem Nothing special. It's just that the Mexico Stock Exchange has facilities for trading foreign securities (SIC), and VOO happens to trade there.

Comment: What kind of facilities?

Comment: @ebepem A category of securities traded on its stock market known as the "Global Market" (SIC). As long as the national regulations and stock exchange regulations allow it, any stock exchange can allow trading in foreign securities.

Comment: If the same ETF can be bough from different places, how to choose the place?

Comment: @ebepem Refer to my answer to your other question: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/145187/from-which-stock-exchange-should-i-buy-etfs