# I got the tip to invest in CSSPX. When I search the symbol at Stocks.app (Yahoo Finance) there are 3 hits. What exactly is the difference?

Tags: etf, market-indexes, yahoo-finance, ticker-symbols

I got the tip to invest in `CSSPX` and `ACWX`. But unfortunately the symbols are not unique, there are several hits in Stocks.app (Yahoo Finance API). What exactly are the differences in the various hits?

[image: CSSPX screenshot]

[image: ACWX screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that they are traded on different stock exchanges, and are traded in different currencies. For example, the screenshot for ACWX shows that it is traded on the NASDAQ (US dollars), Mexican Stock Exchange (Mexican pesos), and Santiago Stock Exchange (US dollars).

Similar questions:

- [Which one is the VOO ETF I'm looking for?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/145185/which-one-is-the-voo-etf-im-looking-for)
- [What do MX, NE, DA, F, etc. mean in the stock market?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/146243/what-do-mx-ne-da-f-etc-mean-in-the-stock-market)

> But unfortunately the symbols are not unique ...

The screenshot for CSSPX shows this clearly. It could either be "Cohen & Steers Global Realty I" or "iShares Core S&P 500 UCITS ETF". To reduce ambiguity in the future, I recommend that in addition to the stock symbol, you know the full name or ISIN/CUSIP/SEDOL of the stock and the stock exchange where it is traded on.